# Set virtualenv name in Fish shell, directly in config.fish

Tags: virtualenv, fish, virtualfish

The documentation of [`virtualfish`](http://virtualfish.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#customizing-your-fish-prompt) specifices that in order to get the fish prompt to show the current `virtualenv` you should update the global `fish_prompt` function and save it (`funced fish_prompt` and funcsave `fish_prompt`). I don't find that approach particular elegant, as I would like to have all my customizations in `config.fish`. My question is therefore, what is the simplest approach to show the current `virtualenv` name in the `fish prompt` by only making changes in `config.fish`?

So if `foobar` is the name of the current environment, how to show it like:

```
(foobar) gedefar@Jakobs-MacBook-Pro ~/w/pyprototypes`
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest approach I found was by overriding the `fish_prompt` function in `config.fish`

```
functions -c fish_prompt _old_fish_prompt
function fish_prompt
  if set -q VIRTUAL_ENV
    echo -n -s (set_color -b blue white) "(" (basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV") ")" (set_color normal) " "
  end
  _old_fish_prompt
end
```

Comment: For noobs to fish like myself, being on a Mac, the whole of above needed to be saved in the following location ~/.config/fish/config.fish for it to work for me. @jakobht thank you for this!